# Using a url as an id in flask

Tags: python, flask

Im making a website and want to get a url from the main website url and when i go to:

example.com/get/https://google.com

Using this route:

`@app.route('/get/<string:url>')`

Instead of setting the variable 'url' to 'https://google.com' i get a Not Found error on the website.

Code for getting the url:

```
@app.route('/get/<string:url>')
def get(url):
  return url
```

Comment: You need to URL encode google address. The colon is not allowed after the URI scheme